# Regex.IsMatch not working after backspace in TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a TextBox with a `LostFocus` event handler that calls a method that formats the string of numbers in the TextBox to a number format. For instance, `123456,78` returns `123 456,78`.
If I instead start with `123 45` it correctly returns `12 345,00`.

However, if I first type `123456,78`, and it correctly returns `123 456,78`, and then delete the last four characters in the TextBox with the backspace key, i.e. I delete `6,78` by clicking backspace four times, it's not working. It just keeps `123 45` in the TextBox.
However, if I select all the text in the TextBox and paste `123 45` it returns `12 345,00` correctly.

When I debug by stepping one line at a time, I see that the method argument `amountIn` correctly stores the string `123 45`, both when I use the backspace keys and when I select and paste. However, `Regex.IsMatch()` returns `false` when I use backspace and `true` when I select and paste.  Hence, I believe that the backspace leaves some kind of artifact in the string that is not visible while debugging but is recognized by the `IsMatch()` method. Here is my method:

```
private void txtAmount_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAmount.Text = ReformatAmount(txtAmount.Text);
}

public static string ReformatAmount(string amountIn)
{
    string amountOut;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(amountIn, @"^[0-9 ,.]+$"))
    {
        amountOut = Regex.Replace(amountIn, "[. ]", "");

        amountOut = Convert.ToDecimal(amountOut).ToString("N");

        return amountOut;
    }
    else
    {
        amountOut = amountIn;
        return amountOut;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like `decimal.TryParse` instead?

Comment: Flydog, I tried your method and it worked as well. A neat solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator) in Sweden is the non-breaking space character, char `0xA0` (160), not char `0x20` (32), the white space commonly used to separate, e.g, words.

You can see it better writing:

```
var cultureSE = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("se-SE");
string hexChar = ((int)cultureSE.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator[0]).ToString("X2");
```

`hexChar` will be `"A0"`.

The Regex in use, `^[0-9 ,.]+$` doesn't account for that, it only considers char `0x20`.
You can change it to just `[0-9 ,.]+` to ignore it, but you probably want to use `\s` instead, it will also match all Unicode white-space chars, including non-breaking white-space chars, as char `0xA0`.
See also: [Character classes in regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions)

The expression can then be changed in:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(amountIn, @"^[0-9\s,.]+$"))
{
     // Convert to a culture-specific number representation
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions:

```cs
string[] nums = new[]
{
  "123456,78",
  "123 456,78",
  "6,78",
  "123 45"
};
foreach (var num in nums)
{
  if (Decimal.TryParse(num, NumberStyles.Any, null, out decimal result))
  {
    // Number successfully parsed:
    Console.WriteLine($"{result:N2}");
  }
  else
  {
    // Parsing error here
    Console.WriteLine($"Could not parse: '{num}'");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
123 456,78
123 456,78
6,78
12 345,00
```

Comment: Since you are parsing user input (which often includes _fat finger_ mistyping), consider `decimal.TryParse` instead of `.Parse`

Comment: This is obvious, but will make it more clear ))